# how to place image src in dist on angular-cli prod build, when website is hosted in a subdomain?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have setup and angular-cli prod build. The image is placed in assets/images/somelogo.png.

I have a website on IIS : **http://localhost:8000/**
I have created a sub-website where I am trying to host the angular-cli build. the url of which is as follows :**http://localhost:8000/a2**

I creating the build as follows :

**ng build --prod --deploy-url /a2**

I have a header component which has an html as follows :

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
<img src="/assets/images/somelogo.png" alt="somelogo" />my image</a>
```

but on deployment the image url is shown as : **/assets/images/somelogo.png**
but I want it to show : **a2/assets/images/somelogo.png**

I also tried changing the base-href by running the following :

**ng build --prod --deploy-url /a2 --base-href /a2**

but that doesn't work either. Can someone please help me with that ?

=========================================================================

I got it fixed by doing the following :

on the template I used :

```
<img [src]="imageSource"/>
```

on the template component I did the following:

```
import {PlatformLocation  } from '@angular/common';
export class MyComponent {
constructor(private platformLocation: PlatformLocation) { 
imageSource:string=this.platformLocation.pathname +'assets/images/somelogo.png';
}
```

platformLocation.pathname takes the base-href and appends it to the path. I am not sure if this is the right solution?

Comment: Try this: `ng build --prod --base-href /a2/`

Comment: Please add your solution as a answer, instead of an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried
    `ng build --prod --base-href .`
and this did the trick, thanks Will Huang for your response

Comment: You should put this as a comment, not as an answer.